# [Power BI][DAX] - Store previously selected value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm working with Power BI and DAX, and I'm wondering if it's possible to write a DAX function that can store the previously selected value for a particular column. Here's an example of what I have in mind:

```
StoredAgeValue = ROUND(AVERAGE('public users'[age]), 0)
```

Let's say I select the country 'USA,' and I get the age value of 5. Now, when I select another country, I want the DAX function to check if the new value is greater or lower than the previously selected value.

Is there a way to achieve this in DAX, and if so, could you provide an example or guide me on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new table for the second country selector and this can remain disconnected (ie no relationship).

Then your second measure would be:

```
StoredAgeValue - 2nd = CALCULATE(
    [StoredAgeValue],
    ALL('public users'[country]),
    'public users'[country] = SELECTEDVALUE('yourNewCountrySelector'[country])
  )
```